# gmaps4rails: can't keep info window open on pan or zoom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm reloading the markers in my map using replaceMarkers().  Everything seems to be working great, but after trying multiple methods, I can't seem to keep an open infowindow open when zooming or panning.  It's especially annoying when the user clicks on a record listed in the sidebar which brings up the info window for a moment - only to disappear once the panning has stopped.

I've tried using visibleInfoWindow to keep track of the window & reopen it once the markers have been reset, but when doing this the newly opened infowindow no longer closes.

I'm guessing that I'm just missing something.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: please create an issue within the github repo and provide a bit more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others will benefit, I have succeeded in keeping the window open by doing the following after calling replaceMarkers():

- Check if window is open using visibleInfoWindow property from the map object
- if window is open, compare previous window object to new windows/markers
- if the same marker/window is still in bounds I call infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.map, marker.serviceObject)

note that I couldn't just use marker in the open call.  I needed to use the serviceObject which has the anchor point & offset properties required.

Answer (score 0):

As an example to this one I have some fairly rough and ready code (coffescript). My example is for a map that reloads each time the map is repositioned. You can see this in action here: http://www.windunit.com/

```
drawItems = (theBounds) ->
  url = "/locations.json/?sw_y=" + theBounds.getSouthWest().lng() + "&sw_x=" + theBounds.getSouthWest().lat() + "&ne_y=" + theBounds.getNorthEast().lng() + "&ne_x=" + theBounds.getNorthEast().lat()
  $.get url, (newItemData) ->
    visibleinfo = Gmaps.map.visibleInfoWindow.content if Gmaps.map.visibleInfoWindow
    Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers newItemData
    if visibleinfo
      for marker in Gmaps.map.markers
        if marker.infowindow.content == visibleinfo
          if Gmaps.map.visibleInfoWindow != null
            Gmaps.map.visibleInfoWindow.close()
          marker.infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.serviceObject, marker.serviceObject)
          Gmaps.map.visibleInfoWindow = marker.infowindow   
          return

Gmaps.map.callback = ->
  google.maps.event.addListener Gmaps.map.serviceObject, "idle", ->
    bounds = Gmaps.map.serviceObject.getBounds()
    drawItems bounds
```